# Im trying to create an navigation menu in ionic but it's unclickable and cuts off my ion-content

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

So I'm new to ionic and to get started I am truing to recreate a blog I had made so that it is not only accessible as a website but as a cross-platform mobile application as well. I was working on the top nav bar when I ran into a problem - the links were not clickable, just static as if were text and only seem responsive in mobile view and even then the menu cuts off the content. I have tried to post as little code as possible but have the files with me so i can add as comments if need be. Thank you in advance

I have tried moving the app-nav tag around, adding (click) which i didnt think i had to if i used routerlink. Adding a toolbar solves the cutting off problem but further eventuates the unresponsiveness as even in mobile view it is unresponsive.

```html
//index.html

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/solid.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/navstyle.css">


</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
//nav.component.html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-fostrap" [ngClass]="{'visible': mobileMenu}">
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="/blogs">Home</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="">About</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="">News </a></li>
      <li><a>About<span class="arrow-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a routerLink="">News </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a routerLink="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bg-fostrap" >
    <div class="navbar-fostrap" (click)="mobileMenuExpand()"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>
    <a routerLink="" class="title-mobile">A2E</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
```

```js
nav.component.ts
  mobileMenuExpand()
  {
    this.mobileMenu = !this.mobileMenu
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.content {
  height: 200px;
}
a { text-decoration: none; }


.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-fostrap {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px 0;
  background: #03A9F4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav-fostrap ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.nav-fostrap li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14;
  color: #def1f0;
}

.nav-fostrap li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 14;
  color: #def1f0;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-fostrap li:hover ul.dropdown { display: block; }

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: #2980B9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  padding-top: 0;
}

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li:last-child a { border-bottom: none; }

.nav-fostrap li:hover a {
  background: #2980B9;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.nav-fostrap li:first-child:hover a { border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; }

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li:hover a { background: rgba(0,0,0, .1); }

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li:first-child:hover a { border-radius: 0; }

.nav-fostrap li:hover .arrow-down { border-top: 5px solid #fff; }

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #def1f0;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  right: -5px;
  content: '';
}
.title-mobile {
  display: none;
}
 @media only screen and (max-width:900px) {

.nav-fostrap {
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.title-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
.nav-fostrap.visible {
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}

.nav-bg-fostrap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #03A9F4;
  padding: 12px 0 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.navbar-fostrap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 12px;
}

.navbar-fostrap span {
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
}

.navbar-fostrap span:nth-child(2) { width: 20px; }

.navbar-fostrap span:nth-child(3) { width: 20px; }

.nav-fostrap ul { padding-top: 50px; }

.nav-fostrap li { display: block; }

.nav-fostrap li a {
  display: block;
  color: #505050;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav-fostrap li:first-child:hover a { border-radius: 0; }

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown { position: relative; }

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li a {
  background: #2980B9 !important;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.nav-fostrap li:hover a {
  background: #03A9F4;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li:hover a {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.nav-fostrap li ul.dropdown li a { padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px; }

.nav-fostrap li:hover .arrow-down { border-top: 5px solid #fff; }

.arrow-down {
  border-top: 5px solid #505050;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
}

.cover-bg {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width:1199px) {

.container { width: 96%; }
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
//blogs.pag.html
<ion-header>

    <app-nav></app-nav>

</ion-header>
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
    <app-blog-item *ngFor="let blog of blogs" [blog]='blog'></app-blog-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I am trying recreate an active navbar that works on ionic as to have a fluid mobile and web experience :< i have tried to post as little code as possible but have the files with me so i can add as comments if need be

Comment: Just : For your function mobileMenuExpand() you can write "this.mobileMenu = !this.mobileMenu". It will do the same.